# oncomplete method doesn't always executes after action, JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have the next scenario (simplified) :

My function in my docsMB managed bean:

```
public void saveAdvance() {
    // by default, finalized is false
    finalized = getFinalizedByBySlowFunction();
}
```

A button in my xhtml:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="SAVE"
action="#{docsMB.saveAdvance}"                              
oncomplete="verifyDocs();"/>
```

And my verifyDocs function in the same xhtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var verifyDocs = function(){
    //alert(1);
    if( #{docsMB.finalized == true} ){
        #{rich:component('mpConfirmar')}.show();
    }
}
</script>
```

This make me a problem.
If I execute my app, "finalized" is always false, but I realized that if I uncomment the alert in the verifyDocs function, it works.
I think the alert gives the "necesary" time to saveAdvance to finalize itself.

What can I do to be sure that the oncomplete method excecutes after the action has finalized?

Or am I doing a mistake in other place?

Thanks a lot

[Edit]

If I refresh the entire page, I get the correct "finalized" value...

Comment: The `oncomplete` method will be executed after the action has finalized. Make sure your bean has View scope (or greater) and that your method is returning the value you need/want (you can make sure in debug or add a log enter for `finalized` value).

Comment: I'm sure. If I just initialize the "finalized" var in the constructor to false, and set it to true in the method, in the javascript function i get false. And the scope is session, and also printing the finalized value with Console.log i get false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when I define the javascript function, it became like static, it means, It just execute once and the variable finalized gets the defined values when the page loads.
So, when I clicked the button it retrieve the value predefined, no te value at that moment. 
But if I refresh the page, the variable gets the value at the moment of the refresh.

So to solve this, I just put my javascript code directly in the oncomplete method and finally WORKS :D

Maybe a better solution could be to find a way to refresh the javascript code each time the button is clicked, because if I put the javascript code in the oncomplete method, it seems dirty, because of the lot of characters in a line.

Comment: I hope you understand that I want to say, because my English is very bad